# How to implement switch with distinct cases?

Tags: c

Here in the followed program if last condition is true then unnecessarily we have to check all conditions before it.
Is there any possibility to implement switch case in the below program?
I've to convert very similar code to this into Arm assembly.

```
main()
{
    int x;

    if (x< 32768)
        x<<15;
    elseif(x<49152)
        (x<<12)- 7;
    elseif(x<53248)
        (x<<11)- 13;
    elseif(x<59392)
        (x<<10)-27;
    elseif(x<60928)
        (x<<9)-61;
    elseif(x<62208)
        (x<<8)-139;
    elseif(x<64128)
        (x<<7)-225;
    elseif(x<65088)
        (x<<6)-414;
    elseif(x<65344)
        (x<<5)-801;
    elseif(x<65488)
        (x<<4)-1595;
    elseif(x<65512)
        (x<<3)-2592;
    elseif(x<65524)
        (x<<2)-4589;
    elseif(x<65534)
        (x<<1)-8586;
}
```

Hope someone will help me.

Comment: No, `switch` statements in C can't be used that way.

Comment: You can try to convert if-else chain to a binary search like to minimize the number of comparisons. For this example you should be able to go down to four checks instead.

Comment: If there is a pattern to integers, then there might be some bit play. Are you trying to convert some stream or packet?

Comment: None of your expressions after each `if` do anything useful. Shouldn't that worry you more?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that with switches since you need to have constant values to compare to x, not boolean conditions. But you can use a struct like this:

```
struct {
   int u_limit;
   int shift_left;
   int add;
} ranges[13] = { {32768, 15, 0}, {49152, 12, -7} /*, ...*/};

for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
   if (x < ranges[i].u_limit) {
      x = x << ranges[i].shift_left + ranges[i].add; break;
   }
}
```

Of course, you can replace the linear search with binary search for some speedup.

Comment: Minor nitpick: That `if` condition should be `x < ranges[i].u_limit`.

Comment: +1 for using search structure. For the 'probably intended' code (as it contains bugs like `elseif` instead of `else if` and no-effent `x<<` instead of `x=<<`) I'd suggest using `boost::flat_set/map` (it is `sorted std::vecotr`). Other possibility would be to optimize if-else structure to actually perform the binary-search in place, but that would be ugly and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 4):

So first things first: are you concerned about performance? If so, do you have *actual* profiling data showing that this code is a hot-spot and *nothing* else shows up on the profile?

I doubt that. In fact, I am willing to bed that you haven't even benchmarked it. You are instead looking at code and trying to micro-optimize it.

If that's the case then the answer is simple: **stop doing that**. Write your code the way it makes sense to write it and focus on improving the algorithmic efficiency of your code. Let the compiler worry about optimizing things. If the performance proves inadequate *then* profile and focus on the results of the profiling. Almost always the answer to your performance problems will use: choose a better-performing algorithm. The answer will almost never be "tinker with an `if` statement".

Now, to answer your question: A `switch` isn't helpful in this scenario because there's no *sane* way to represent the concept `x < 32768` in a `case` statement, short of writing one statement for every such value of `x`. Obviously this is neithe practical nor sane.

More importantly you seem to operate under the misconception that a `switch` would translate to fewer comparisons. It's possible in *some* rare cases for a compiler to be able to avoid comparisons, but most of the time a `switch` will mean as many comparisons as you have `case` statements. So if you need to check a variable against 10000 different possible values using a `switch`, you'll get 10000 comparisons.

In your case, you're checking for way more than 10,000 possible values, so the simple `if` construct combined with the "less than" operator makes a lot more sense and will be much more efficient than a `switch`.

You write that "*Here in the followed program if last condition is true then unnecessarily we have to check all conditions before it.*" True, you do. You could rewrite it so that if the last condition were true you would only need two comparisons. But then you'd simply flip the problem on it's head: if `x< 32768` you'd end up having to check all the other possible values so you'd be back where you started.

One possible solution would be to perform binary search. This would certainly qualify as an algorithmic improvement, but again without hard data that this is, indeed, a hotspot, this would be a rather silly exercise.

The bottom line is this: write correct code that is both easy to understand and easy to maintain and improve and don't worry about reordering `if` statements. The excellent answer by perreal shows a good example of simple and easy to understand and maintain code.

And on the topic of writing correct code, there's no such thing as `elseif` in C and C++. Which brings us to my last point: before micro-optimizing code at least try to run the compiler.

Comment: +1: good point on `elseif`, similarly one can remove all no-side-effect ops such as `(x<<1)-8586;` and suddenly all code is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your comments & answers. Its just a sample code which is very similar to actual code. It may not be useful to you but it is helpful to me @perreal, Nik Bougalis, Jongware